# Как спарсить информацию с сайта?

Tags: android, jsoup, parse

Подскажите как спарсить ифу, которая доступна только после нажатия на кнопку.
До кнопки все просто.
Вот так:

```
try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("" + editText.getText().toString().trim()).get();
        Elements tables = doc.getElementsByClass("request_route");
        Elements tables2 = doc.getElementsByClass("cargo_type");
        Elements tables3 = doc.getElementsByClass("date_add");
        Elements tables4 = doc.getElementsByClass("truck_type");
        Elements tables5 = doc.getElementsByClass("weight");
        Elements tables6 = doc.getElementsByClass("cube");
        Elements tables7 = doc.getElementsByClass("price_main");

        if (tables != null
                && tables2 != null
                && tables3 != null
                && tables4 != null
                && tables5 != null
                && tables6 != null
                && tables7 != null) {

        for (int a = 0; a < tables5.size(); a++) {
            ListItemClass items = new ListItemClass();
            items.setName(tables.get(a).text());
            items.setZagol(tables2.get(a).text());
            items.setType_Car(tables4.get(a).text());
            //items.setCube(tables6.get(a).text());
            items.setCube("0 cbm");
            items.setDate(tables3.get(a).text());

           if(!tables5.get(a).text().contains("-") ) {
               st_wght = tables5.get(a).text().substring(0, tables5.get(a).text().indexOf("т"));

               st_wght = st_wght.replace(",", ".");
               try {
                   in_weigh = Double.parseDouble(st_wght);
               } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                   in_weigh = 0;
               }
               items.setWeght(st_wght);
           }else{
               items.setWeght(tables5.get(a).text());
           }


            arrayList.add(items);
        }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("qwe", "1 " + e.getMessage());

    }
```

А дальше там div class = "value" =>  <a href => ...a>

Comment: Не вполне понятно что именно вы хотите сделать и в чём именно проблема. Кажется, вам нужно просто по ссылке опять сделать запрос и распарсить что-то. Если же вы про какой-то контент, динамически на страницу через JS добавляемый говорите, то надо логи запроса в консоли браузера искать и запрос повторять. В худшем случае - переходить на совсем другую технологию - виртуальный браузер типа Selenium

Comment: Та сижу тут развлекаюсь с сайтом. Все его данные доступны на одной странице. Но вот конкретно номер телефона показывается только по нажатию на кнопку и тогда item открывается больше. Вот не знаю как от туда номер телефона взять. Может кроме jsoup еще какие варианты есть? Мне надо в свое приложение перенести некоторые данные. Иначе прийдется вручную телефон добавлять. А это такое себе занятие.

Comment: Я вам уже всё расписал выше - смотрите в консоли браузера что происходит при нажатии кнопки и выбирайте один из описанных выше вариантов.